# ubuntu 11.10 не загружается

Tags: ubuntu

Установил ubuntu 11.10 на отдельный раздел. При установке выделил место для grub (ext4) "/boot" в том же разделе, под swap и под саму систему "/". После установки и перезагрузки как обычно грузится windows. Что-нибудь тут можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставить *grub* в MBR, и прописать в `grub.conf` загрузку Windows, чтобы иметь возможность загружать как Linux так и Windows.